# Select documents where array is specific length

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to match documents where the array size is equal to `2`.

With these documents:

```
{ path: ['a', 'b'] }
{ path: ['a', 'b', 'c'] }
{ path: ['1', '2'] }
{ path: ['1', '2', '3'] }
```

I am trying to select the first and the third item. I tried using this but it returns no documents.

```
{
  $match: {
    path: { $eq: [{ $size: '$path' }, 2] }
  }
}
```

I also tried this, but it gives me an error:

```
{
  $match: {
    $eq: [{ $size: '$path' }, 2]
  }
}
```

> Expected "[" or AggregationStage but "{" found.

Comment: You have to [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) to call aggregation function in match stage. Something like `{"$match":{"$expr":{"$eq":[{"$size":"$path"},2]}}}`

Comment: It should be `db.collection.find({ $expr: { $eq: [{ "$size": "$path" }, 2 ] } })`

Comment: That gives me **unknown top level operator: `$expr`**

Comment: It appears you are not on version 3.6. For equality you can use regular size query operator. `{$match:{ path:{ $size : 2 }}}` More [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/)